# Disabled buttons not visible in /review on some sites

Tags: bug, review, design

On some sites, when using the review queues, the button which is disabled (because it's not compatible with your (lack of) actions so far) has become invisible:

[image]

([MathOverflow](https://mathoverflow.net))

[image]

([Puzzling Stack Exchange](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com))

For an example of how it did (and should) look like, this is the situation on Stack Overflow:

[image]

I originally posted the [bug](/questions/tagged/bug) [here](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/q/3872/70594) but it seems to be an issue on more sites. It *could* be that the new site theme will fix things; for a similar problem on Ask Different I posted a bug report [here](https://apple.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3217/121968) and it has been fixed. That specific problem still affects [The Workplace](https://i.stack.imgur.com/seHVu.png).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that the new responsive design has fixed this issue:

[image]